# Multiple queries resulting in minimum number of occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the smallest number of documents retrieved by any subject based on exp_condition. Exp_condition from the subjects table contains a '1' and a '2' column.

Here are the tables:
subjects table:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| Field           | Type         |
+-----------------+--------------+
| username        | varchar(255) |
| user_type       | varchar(10)  |
| years           | int          |
| low_grade       | int          |
| high_grade      | int          |
| on_line         | varchar(10)  |
| on_line_sources | varchar(255) |
| location        | varchar(5)   |
| exp_condition   | int          |
+-----------------+--------------+
tasks table:

+------------+--------------+
| Field      | Type         |
+------------+--------------+
| username   | varchar(255) |
| task       | varchar(5)   |
| confidence | int          |
| sim_helpd  | int          |
+------------+--------------+
```

docs table:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| Field        | Type         |
+--------------+--------------+
| username     | varchar(255) |
| task         | varchar(5)   |
| doc_type     | varchar(10)  |
| used_tool    | int          |
| relevant     | int          |
| motivational | int          |
| concepts     | int          |
| background   | int          |
| grade_level  | int          |
| hands_on     | int          |
| attachments  | int          |
+--------------+--------------+
```

I'm able to generate the number of subjects and number of documents for both exp_condition values. I'm allowed to use multiple queries, but I'm not sure how.

Code for generating number of subjects for exp_condition 1 and 2:

```
select count(distinct(t2.username)) 
from tasks as t1 
inner join subjects as t2 
on t1.username = t2.username group by exp_condition;
```

Code for generating number of documents for exp_condition 1 and 2:

```
select count(*), exp_condition 
from docs as t1 
left join subjects as t2 
on t1.username = t2.username 
group by exp_condition;
```

Expected output: two separate numbers for smallest number of documents retrieved by any subject based on exp_condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is not a function. `distinct (a)` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery or a CTE

SubQuery

```
SELECT exp_condition, MIN(A) as Tasks, MIN(B) as Docs FROM (
    SELECT exp_condition, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.username) A, COUNT(DISTINCT (t3.username) B
    FROM subjects s
    LEFT JOIN tasks T2 ON s.username = t2.username
    LEFT JOIN docs T3 ON s.username = t3.username
    GROUP BY exp_condition
) A
GROUP BY ex_condition
```

CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT exp_condition, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.username) A, COUNT(DISTINCT (t3.username) B
        FROM subjects s
        LEFT JOIN tasks T2 ON s.username = t2.username
        LEFT JOIN docs T3 ON s.username = t3.username
        GROUP BY exp_condition
)
SELECT exp_condition, MIN(A) as Tasks, MIN(B) as Docs 
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY ex_condition
```